# Angular directive controller - wait for assignment/evaluation of attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

lets say I have the following tag:

```
<input name="username" type="text" ng-model="vm.username" available="{{vm.blarg}}">
```

lets say that `blarg` is set to "foo" (from the controller of the page - not from the below directive).

and I have the following directive:

```
  angular.module('app')
    .directive('available', RegistrationCtrl);

  function RegistrationCtrl() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=ngModel'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        console.log("link: " + attrs.available); //output: "foo"
      },
      controller: ExampleController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
  }

  function ExampleController($attrs) {
    console.log("controller:" + $attrs.available); //output: "{{vm.blarg}}"
  }
```

My questions: is there any way to make the controller (of the directive) wait until the moment after which all the attributes are parsed (evaluated) by angular:

```
{{vm.blarg}} -> "foo"
```

In other words, I would like the directive to run only after the first digest cycle is finished.

Comment: Instead of using available="{{vm.blarg}}" use available="vm.blarg" then add angular watch on vm.blarg in your available directive then proceed ur logic there.

Comment: What do you mean by, "directive to run only after the first digest cycle"? A directive compiles every time its scope modifies.

Comment: @manasisakhare, it seems like the controller runs before the vm.blarg is not being evaluated. but after a some time (I think after the digest cycle finishes - the expression vm.barg is being evaluated by the parent controller of the directive and parsed to "foo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the angular docs, the best practice is:

> use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives.
>   Otherwise use link.

In your directive, If there are no API's to expose, then do not use controller. All your logic goes in link function, where you can watch your scope attributes for change.